# Persist Session Cookie in Scrapy

Tags: python, cookies, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping a site that has an accept terms form that I need to click through. When I click the button I am redirected to the resource that needs to be scraped. I have the basic mechanics working, that is the initial click through works and I get a session and all goes well until the session times out. Then for some reason Scrapy does get redirected but the response URL doesn't get updated so I get duplicate items since I am using the URL to check for duplication.

For example the URL I am requesting is:

```
https://some-internal-web-page/Records/Details/119ce2b7-35b4-4c63-8bd2-2bfbf77299a8
```

But when the session expires I get:

```
https://some-internal-web-page/?returnUrl=%2FRecords%2FDetails%2F119ce2b7-35b4-4c63-8bd2-2bfbf77299a8
```

Here is my code:

```
 # function to get through accept dialog
def parse(self, response):
    yield FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={"value":"Accept"}, callback=self.after_accept)

# function to parse markup
def after_accept(self, response):

    global latest_inspection_date

    urls = ['http://some-internal-web-page/Records?SearchText=&SortMode=MostRecentlyHired&page=%s&PageSize=25' % page for page in xrange(1,500)]

    for u in urls:
        yield Request( u, callback=self.parse_list )
```

So my question is, how do I persist and/or refresh the session cookie so that I don't get the redirect URL instead of the URL I need.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are enabled by default and passed through every callback, make sure you have it enabled with [`COOKIES_ENABLED=True`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#cookies-enabled) in `settings.py`.

you can also enable debugging logs for it with `COOKIES_DEBUG=True` (`False` by default), and check if the cookies are being passed correctly, so maybe your problem is about something else.

Comment: Thanks for that! I had it enabled but your advice made me look elsewhere. The problem seems to be that in the request for the page I am directed to the accept form but then the session is found and I am redirected. However, the response.url doesn't seem to be updated because when it gets to the callback it still has the redirect url. I know I am on the right page though because the data gets scraped. Why doesn't requests update the response url? This is all I am doing: yield Request(url=details_url, callback=self.parse_details)

Comment: what do you mean with `response.url` not being updated? every response is being controlled if its respective callback, so if you are yielding a `Request`, the respective `Response` object will be caught on the `callback` method you specified on the `Request.`

Comment: Scrapy has the list of URL's for detail pages (e.g. https://some-internal-web-page/Records/Details/119ce2b7...) but when it gets around to actually requesting it (supposing that the session is stale), the accept form is returned, the session is checked and then the request is made. But the response.url I get in parse_details is the redirect URL (e.g. https://some-internal-web-page/?returnUrl=%2FRecords%2FDetails%2F119ce2b7) and not the URL of the details page. So it seems to me that the URL that Requests passes to parse_details isn't updated after the 301.

Comment: looks to me that you should do a following request (in `parse_details`) to the actual page again (remember to put `dont_filter=True` in the Request so it isn't filtered as duplicate). Please also check the `response.status` if it is a redirection status, maybe you have deactivated the [RedirectMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect)